# How to consider comma in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

DATA:

```
"address": "198 Mill Lane"
"address": "200 Mill, Lane"
```

Search:

```
 POST /bank/_search?pretty
    {
       "query": {
        "match_phrase": {
           "address": "Mill, Lane"
        }
      }
    }
```

Problem:
This search returns the both DATA in the Index. I need only one as result because i was searched with 
"Mill, Lane" Elastic search need to consider the comma but it won't consider it. How to attain my result? Please advise.

Comment: It depends on how you indexed the documents. The standard tokenizer will extract tokens from your text based on punctuation, empty spaces etc. So, your data gets into ES inverted index like "198", "Mill", "Lane", "200", "Mill", "Lane". So, no commas. If you want to, indeed, search like that you need to use a different tokenizer or mark the field as "not_analyzed".

Comment: @AndreiStefan probably concise enough for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is OK to not match "Mill ,Lane" or "Mill , Lane" to any document, then you can use the `whitespace` analyzer provided out of the box by Elasticsearch.

First, create a custom mapping by executing the following command (replace `<index name>` with the actual index name):

```
PUT <index name>/_mapping/whitespace_analyzer
{
    "whitespace_analyzer": {
        "properties" : {
            "address" : {
                "type" : "string",
                "analyzer" : "whitespace"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Next, index your documents using the mapping created above with commands like

```
POST <index name>/whitespace_analyzer
{
    "address" : "198 Mill Lane"
}

POST <index name>/whitespace_analyzer
{
    "address" : "200 Mill, Lane"
}
```

Now you can use the same `match_phrase` query as you mentioned to get the desired results.

```
{
    "query" : {
        "match_phrase" : {
            "address": "Mill, Lane"
        }
    }
}
```

As the name suggests, `whitespace` analyzer tokenizes with whitespaces as delimiters. Hence the terms that get indexed will be "198", "Mill", "Lane", "200" and "Mill,". Search API uses the same analyzer used by the Index API if not explicitly mentioned. Above is a very simple analyzer. You can learn how to build more sophisticated custom analyzers [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/custom-analyzers.html).

Comment: @Kirupa If this answers your question please mark it as an answer. Let me know if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you indexed the documents. The standard tokenizer will extract tokens from your text based on punctuation, empty spaces etc. So, your data gets into ES inverted index like "198", "Mill", "Lane", "200", "Mill", "Lane". So, no commas.

If you want to, indeed, search like that you need to use a different tokenizer or mark the field as `not_analyzed`.

EDIT: solution with custom analyzer

- define a nGram analyzer for your index and associate this custom analyzer with the `address` field:

```
PUT /myindex
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_ngram_analyzer": {
          "tokenizer": "my_ngram_tokenizer"
        }
      },
      "tokenizer": {
        "my_ngram_tokenizer": {
          "type": "nGram",
          "min_gram": "2",
          "max_gram": "25",
          "token_chars": [
            "letter",
            "digit",
            "punctuation",
            "whitespace"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "mytype": {
      "properties": {
        "address" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "analyzer" : "my_ngram_analyzer"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- when searching, use a `phrase` type match:

```
GET /myindex/mytype/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "address": {
        "query": "Mill, Lane",
        "type": "phrase"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If i add indexed = not_analyzed means, how can i able to search the above? It will return 0 result if i search for the keyword "Mill, Line"

Comment: If this is possible means, could you please provide the JSON?